# LabVIEW driver, block diagrams not showing up

Tags: driver, labview, gpib

I installed the driver for the [Keithley 6485](http://www.tek.com/specialty-instruments/6485-software/models-6485-6487-and-6514-ivi-visa-based-driver-visual-basic-v-0). However, the block diagrams do not show up after the install. There is a KE6485 folder in `inst.lib`, but the LabVIEW files are in LabVIEW library files. Unlocking them as individual files does not change this situation.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by *the block diagrams do not show up*. Do you mean you can't find the Keithley VIs in the palette, or do you mean you can see the VIs but you want to look at their block diagrams?

Comment: The VIs don't show up in the palette.
However, there are other instruments in the `inst.lib` folder, and I can find those VIs in the palette.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered the issue. The Keithley drivers were only in the 32 bit Labview folder and I was using the 64 bit Labview program.

Comment: It's for this reason that most LabVIEW developers stick to 32 bit. More libraries, better chance of being supported on deployment. There are even core LabVIEW libraries that haven't been ported to 64 bits yet.

Comment: It's weird that another instrument driver was only 64 bit ... although I can load it in the 32 bit Labview